# Dynamic amount of bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

So I am trying to make an undetermined amount of bindParam calls within a foreach, but for some reason it fails. I know the $sql variable is working fine, but I am pretty sure it is failing at the bindParam. Is there any reason for this?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $row1["rand"] . " (" . $areas . ") VALUES (" . $vals . ")";
echo $sql;
$entry2 = $conn->prepare("'".$sql."'");
//echo "swag";
foreach($splitHeader as $element){
    if(strlen($element)>0) {
        $thisVal = "':" . $element . "'";
        $entry2->bindParam($thisVal,$_POST[$element]);
    }
}
$entry2->execute();
```

Comment: Remove the `"'"` stuff at your `prepare()` call. It's just `$conn->prepare($sql);`

Comment: Are you checking for errors after `prepare()` or do you have PDO exceptions enabled? It would tell you that an SQL statement inside quotes is a syntax error.

Comment: You're also putting single-quotes around the parameter name when you make `$thisVal`. You don't need those. You also don't need the `:` prefix in `$thisVal`.

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters that you define in the query must match the number of parameters that you bind.

You would need to loop twice trough your data : once to dynamically construct a sql statement (that you can then  `prepare`), and then a second time to bind the parameters, before finally calling `execute`.

Here is an adaptation of your code that demonstrates the principle :

```
$cols = "";
$vals = "";
foreach( $splitHeader as $element ) {
    if( strlen($element) > 0 ) {
        if ( strlen($cols) > 0 ) {
            $cols .= ", ";
            $vals .= ", ";
        }
        $cols .= $element;
        $vals .= "?";
    }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $row1["rand"] . " (". $cols . ") VALUES(". $vals . ")";
echo $sql;
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);

$i = 1;
foreach($splitHeader as $element){
    if( strlen($element) > 0 ) {
        $sth->bindParam( $i, $_POST[$element] );
        $i++;
    }
}

$sth->execute();
```